# ChangeNotifier Property doesn't Update (Flutter2)

Tags: flutter, dart

On trying to change App theme using a single instance global property defined in a  Change Notifier class ([code](https://itnext.io/an-easy-way-to-switch-between-dark-and-light-theme-in-flutter-fb971155eefe)), the  property `_isDark` used to  monitor the current app theme doesn't change at all eventhough the change function gets executed.

Tried defining it as both instance and static but the property simply doesn't update.

Also couldn't find the `!=` (not equal to)  [operator in the Bool class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/bool-class.html)

How to resolve this?

***Output:***

```
switchTheme()  _isDark = true
Listener -> Change Theme
switchTheme()  _isDark = true
Listener -> Change Theme
switchTheme()  _isDark = true
Listener -> Change Theme
```

***changeTheme.dart:***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTheme extends ChangeNotifier{

  static bool _isDark = true;//Not updating in switchTheme()
  // bool _isDark = true; //Not updating in switchTheme()


 void switchTheme(){
    _isDark != _isDark;//Avoid unnecessary statements Android Studio
    print('switchTheme()  _isDark = $_isDark');
    notifyListeners();
 }

  ThemeMode currentTheme(){
    return _isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
  }
```

***config.dart:***

```
library config.dart ;
import 'changeTheme.dart';

MyTheme myTheme = MyTheme();
```

***homeScreen.dart :***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'config.dart';
import 'changeTheme.dart';

void main(){runApp(
    MyApp());
    }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.light(),
        darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
        themeMode: myTheme.currentTheme(),

        home: HomeScreen(),
      );

  }
  }



class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    myTheme.addListener(() {
    print('Listener -> Change Theme');
    setState(() {

    });
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children : [
        Positioned(
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,

          child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,

          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              myTheme.switchTheme();
            } ,
            style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor:  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.orangeAccent)),
            child: Text('Change Theme '),
          ),
      ),
        ),
     ]) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Also , why isn't there a != operator for bool in dart? Android Studio marks the statement as unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to switch the theme, use `_isDark = !_isDark;` (and not `!=`) to change a boolean with its opposite.